# jNetPcap acknowledgement value

Tags: java, networking, wireshark, jnetpcap

im trying to retrieve the ack from the tcp like the one wireshark returns. In wireshark it returns an ack of 1 or 647. But when i'm trying to get the ack from the packet it returns a long number that is nothing similar to the ack wireshark returns.

I get these acks:

1918004163
3350411129
3083820792
1730247758
3668869711
4218577993

This is my code:

```
 if (packet.hasHeader(tcp) && packet.hasHeader(ip)) {
                        long tcpack = packet.getHeader(tcp).ack();

                        String name = packet.getHeader(tcp).getName();
                        int urgent = packet.getHeader(tcp).urgent();
                        int windowScaled = packet.getHeader(tcp).windowScaled();
                        int window = packet.getHeader(tcp).window();
                        int wirelen = packet.getCaptureHeader().wirelen();
                        // System.out.println("WireLen: "+wirelen);
                        int caplen = packet.getCaptureHeader().caplen();
                        // System.out.println("caplen: "+caplen);
                        String ipTypeString = ip.typeEnum().toString();
                        // System.out.println("IP Type: "+ipTypeString);
                        String ipDescription = ip.getDescription();
                        // System.out.println("IP Description: "+ipDescription);
                        byte[] dIP = packet.getHeader(ip).destination();
                        byte[] sIP = packet.getHeader(ip).source();
                        String sourceIP = FormatUtils.ip(sIP);
                        // System.out.println("Source IP: "+sourceIP);
                        String destinationIP = FormatUtils.ip(dIP);
                        // System.out.println("Destination IP: "+destinationIP);
                        int tcpPORTSource = tcp.source();
                        // System.out.println("TCP PORT Source:
                        // "+tcpPORTSource);
                        int tcpPORTDestination = tcp.destination();
                        // System.out.println("TCP PORT Destination:
                        // "+tcpPORTDestination);
                        if (sourceIP.equals("someip") && tcpPORTSource == 0000 && ipTypeString.equals("TCP")
                                && wirelen == 1514) {
//                          System.out.println("TCP ack: "+tcpack+" name: "+name+ " urgent: "+urgent + " window scaled: "+windowScaled+ " window: "+window);
                        }
```

How do i retrieve the same ack value as wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The numbers you are seeing in wireshark is those in `No.` column, right? They are assigned by wireshark and not info that is available in packets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark by default, shows *relative* sequence numbers for TCP packets.
(I.e., sequence numbers relative to the actual sequence number used at the start of the TCP connection). This makes it easier to view/use the sequence numbers.

There's a preference under the TCP protocol in Wireshark to show TCP *absolute* sequence numbers (those actually used in the TCP packets).

Once you configure Wirehark to show absolute TCP sequence numbers, I expect they'll match the values you are getting with your code.

Exercise for the reader: why doesn't each TCP connection start with actual sequence number 1 ?       :)   :)